# How to get input values in Jquery Array on click submit where quantity is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table is Here:

```html
<div id="MyItems">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>Quantity</tr>
      <tr>Items</tr>
      <tr>Cost</tr>
      <tr>Totals</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="AllItems">
      <tr class="trbody">
        <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
        <td class="items">Test Item 1</td>
        <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">1349</span></td>
        <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trbody">
        <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
        <td class="items">Test Item 2</td>
        <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">854</span></td>
        <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

This is my js code which is triggered after button click. I am retrieving the values of all inputs in an array but stuck how to move forward.

```
jQuery('#form_event').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('.loader').css('display', 'block');
      var id = jQuery('#getitemid').val();
      var totalAmount = jQuery('#TotalAmount').text();
      var ItemArray = [];

      $('#getprices tbody tr').each(function () {
        $(".quantity").each(function() {
          if( $(this).val() !== 0) {
            ItemArray[$(this).attr("quantity")] = $(this).val();
          }
        });

        $(".price").each(function() {
          ItemArray[$(this).attr("price")] = $(this).val();
        });

      });
});
```

[image]

The image of table is given below. Now What I want is to get value of all inputs in an array when I click to submit button. Only the quantity more than 0 should be added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you attempted to solve this problem, where did you get stuck? Can you show your best attempt, and explain what went wrong and what didn't work? Please see the "*[mcve]*", and the "*[ask]*", guidelines. Also, you ask for the array when you "*click to submit,*" but haven't included any submission elements and there is no `<form>`. How is the submission handled?

Comment: @DavidThomas Just updated the question where I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first give id to your table.

```
 <div id="MyItems">    
<table id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>Quantity</tr>
          <tr>Items</tr>
          <tr>Cost</tr>
          <tr>Totals</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="AllItems">
          <tr class="trbody">
            <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
            <td class="items">Test Item 1</td>
            <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">1349</span></td>
            <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="trbody">
            <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
            <td class="items">Test Item 2</td>
            <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">854</span></td>
            <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    
      </table> </div>
```

here's button function

```
$("#Button").click(function (){  
      var myTable= document.getElementById('table');  
       
      var dataArr = []
       
      $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function (a, b) {
        let qty= $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input').val()
        let item = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
        let cost = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
        let total = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").text();
        if (qty !=0){
          dataArr.push({qty: qty, item:item, cost:cost, total:total})  
        } 
        console.log(dataArr)

      }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of each individual quantity.

```
function totalAmount() {
  const quantities = document.getElementsByName('quantity');
  let totalAmount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
    if (quantities[i].value > 0) {
      for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(quantities[i].value); j++) {
        totalAmount += parseInt(quantities[i].parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0].innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(totalAmount);
}
```

Comment: But I want data of items as well. I want to pass the data of items in an array which are selected. Total amount is working fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
$("#yourSubmitButton").click(function (){
    let quantity = $('.quantity').map((_,el) => el.value > 0 ? el.value : null).get();
    console.log(quantity)
})
```

```html
<div id="MyItems">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>Quantity</tr>
      <tr>Items</tr>
      <tr>Cost</tr>
      <tr>Totals</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="AllItems">
      <tr class="trbody">
        <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
        <td class="items">Test Item 1</td>
        <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">1349</span></td>
        <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trbody">
        <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
        <td class="items">Test Item 2</td>
        <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">854</span></td>
        <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <button id="yourSubmitButton">Button</button> 

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. This will give the total price as the output when the user presses submit button. It also keeps track of the number of items the user selects and stores them in array `items` from which, you can retrieve them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MyItems">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>Quantity</tr>
                <tr>Items</tr>
                <tr>Cost</tr>
                <tr>Totals</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="AllItems">
                <tr class="trbody">
                    <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
                    <td class="items">Test Item 1</td>
                    <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">1349</span></td>
                    <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="trbody">
                    <td class="qty amount" id="amount1"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="Qty." class="quantity"></td>
                    <td class="items">Test Item 2</td>
                    <td class="price">$<span class="price-given">854</span></td>
                    <td class="total">$<span class="amount">0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <button class="my-btn">Submit</button>
        <div id="price-total"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.my-btn').click(() =>{
            var items = []
            var total = 0
            $('.trbody').each((index, element) =>{
                var quantity = parseInt($($('#amount1 > input').get(index)).val())
                var price = parseFloat($('#AllItems > tr:nth-child('+(index+1)+') > td.price > span').html())
                if (quantity > 0){
                    items.push(quantity)
                    total += quantity * price
                }
            })
            var text = $('#price-total').text('$'+total)
            console.log(items)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```